# When does the integral $\int_0^1x^q\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{\sin(x)}\right)\,dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

When does the integral $$\int_0^1 x^q\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{\sin(x)}\right)\,dx$$ converge?
So function $$x^q\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{\sin(x)}\right)=x^{q-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right)\le x^{q-1}\implies$$ integral converges when $q-1>-1\implies q>0$. But it doesn't right because Wolfram says it converges when $q=-1$.

Comment: HINT: $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)$

Comment: A further hint: $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+o(x)$, and $x-x^3/6=x(1-x^2/6)$. Use both of these expansions to compute an asymptotic for $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ near $x=0$. What went wrong in your approach is that $1-\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$ is "better than bounded", since it goes to zero at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. There is only a *potential* issue as $x \to 0^+$, but in this case, by the Taylor series expansion of $\sin (\cdot)$, one gets
$$
x^q\left(\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{x^{q+1}}{6}+O\left(x^{q+3} \right)
$$ which converges *iff* $-q-1<1$ that is *iff* $q>-2$.